# Spring MVC - RequestMethod "Post" not supported

Tags: html, spring, angular, http

in my HTML I wrote

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:8080/uploadXML"> 

    <input type="file" id="importFile" /> <br>
    <button type="submit" class="buttonUpload" >Upload</button>
</form>
```

My Controller looks like:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {



@RequestMapping(value="/uploadXML", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload( 
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        String name = "test11";
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            BufferedOutputStream stream = 
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name + "-uploaded")));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
            return "You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + name + "-uploaded !";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
    }
}
```

I always get the error code 405 when pressing the submit button: 
"There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported". 
[This is what my package explorer looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mF7dC.png)

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>springboot-angularjs</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot-angularjs</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.6</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
<groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
<version>2.2.5</version>
 <exclusions>
<exclusion>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
 </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
<version>2.2.5</version>
 <exclusions>
<exclusion>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
     </dependency>


   </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Can someone see my mistake and can explain to me how the file-transfer can work? Thank you so much!

Comment: Please add exception stacktrace.

Comment: "http://localhost:8080/uploadXMLFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Comment: Please add server side logs and also add your spring configuration.

Comment: Do you mean my pom.xml for the configuration?

Comment: can you add your browser post request and their parmemeters  in the question

Comment: This is the browsers output:  ------WebKitFormBoundaryI7J8cPnUcauDgSBw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="irgendwas"; filename="example.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml


------WebKitFormBoundaryI7J8cPnUcauDgSBw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="wasanderes"


------WebKitFormBoundaryI7J8cPnUcauDgSBw--

Comment: Instead of `@RequestParam`, use `@RequestPart` and add attribute `consumes="multipart-form-data"`.

Comment: If I use RequestPart instead of RequestParam and add the attribute consume=".... to my input. Nothing has changed. I get the error even when I remove the whole code in my controller, so there has to be a big mistake somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

try by adding root context i.e dynamic project name in url , like below

http://localhost:8080/XXXXX/uploadXML

XXXXX would be root context name.